# CocoaPods custom prefix header

Tags: cocoapods, pch

In my release build I want to use a `#define` for my whole workspace (including all pods). I did this via the prefix header for my main project, but this doesn't affect my used pods.

How can I add the `#define` macro?

I've seen [Gist 833](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/833) but the last replay was in June '14 and there is no real solution. I've also seen suggestions to use the post_install hook and add it to the pods-environment.h but all solutions I can find are for older version and it seems the have been a lot of structure changes before (or with) 0.35 (which I'm using).

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm on the same problem... Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Sadly not. If you find one, I'd still be interested

Comment: I asked a quite similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872130/how-do-i-access-a-macro-defined-in-my-pch-from-a-cocoapods-lib)... No news yet.